# Cannot make static reference to a non-static method

Tags: java

I'm getting the `Cannot make static reference to a non-static method` error but I don't appear to be making a static reference.. my code is something like the following...

```
 public void run() {
   MyClass mc = new MyClass();
   mc.method();
 }

 public void MyClass(){
   myothermethod(); //error here.
 }
```

I've create a new instance of my class so the reference wont be static but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myothermethod();`

this must be *non static* method available in the **same class**